# 1.9.1.0 - Magento Price hook / extension on product page for configurable products

Tags: ce-1.9.1.0

i have some big problems with prices on the product page. I want to sell t-shirts and other things with printing and configurable prices.

50x t-shirt                                              50x  6,95 €

with  50x printing 1 color "black"                       50x  0,15 €

and **1x pre costs** for printing                 **1x    69,- €**

My problem is the 1x pre costs.

**Magento calculate** 50x 6,95  + 50x 0,15 + **50x 69,- €**

how can i add the position "pre costs" only 1x ?

Please help with your ideas.

Is there an extension? (hook)

Many thanks for your help

Comment: maybe taking a look at a bundle product?

Comment: Yes i've done - but i need an absolute price not a bundle.

Comment: try out this https://magecomp.com/magento-custom-options-absolute-price.html